# INSERT data INTO json column in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to transfer data between tables.

- source table: 2 columns (title_english, title_german), CHAR
- target table: 1 column (titles), JSON

and tried this:

> ```
> INSERT INTO 
> movies (titles) 
> SELECT 
> '{ "en": title_english, "de": title_german}'
> FROM movies_old;
> ```

which gave me an error:

```
Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value."
```

It looks like I could use concat in the SELECT clause:

```
CONCAT('{"en": "',title_english,'","de": "',title_german,'"}')
```

but wonder if there might be a more natural way.

Comment: Hi @Dirkiboy, please let us know if any of our answers helped you.

Comment: @JaredDunham Perfect. That works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON_OBJECT`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html

For example:

`SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', 87, 'name', 'carrot');`

Will produce:

`{"id": 87, "name": "carrot"}`

So your query would look like:

```
INSERT INTO 
movies (titles) 
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('en', title_english, 'de', title_german)
FROM movies_old;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('en',`title_english`, 'de', `title_german`) FROM movies_old;
```